# Only want to return rows that have duplicate unitid within group by unitid

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, bids

I am working in SSRS querying against an oracle database.

So I have a data source and this report is supposed to find duplicate Work Orders based on multiple open workorders on a unique unitid.  So I only want to show groups that have more then one entry as they are grouped by unitid.

```
 SELECT
 COMPSTSB.UNITID,
 COMPSTSB.UNITTYPE,
 ACTDEFN.ACTDESC,
 ACTDEFN.ACTCODE,
 HISTORY.WONO, 
 HISTORY.COMPFLAG,
 HISTORY.ADDDTTM,
 HISTORY.COMMENTS
 FROM   (IMSV7.COMPSTSB COMPSTSB INNER JOIN IMSV7.HISTORY HISTORY ON
 COMPSTSB.COMPKEY=HISTORY.COMPKEY) INNER JOIN IMSV7.ACTDEFN ACTDEFN ON 
 HISTORY.ACTKEY=ACTDEFN.ACTKEY
 WHERE  HISTORY.COMPFLAG='Y' AND  NOT (ACTDEFN.ACTCODE='DBR' OR     ACTDEFN.ACTCODE='IN')
 ORDER BY COMPSTSB.UNITTYPE, COMPSTSB.UNITID, HISTORY.ADDDTTM
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  And yes before someone says this has been asked a million times, I did search.  Point me to the million times and I will see if I feel they match my question.  Ideally in the SQL I could make new column that returned a count of the unitid and I did attempt this but failed, and then I could filter on that column to remove any that only had one count.  I really don't think this should be difficult but I have spent about 4 hours on it so far.

Thanks in advance!
Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, the following should give you what's needed :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT
 COMPSTSB.UNITID,
 COMPSTSB.UNITTYPE,
 ACTDEFN.ACTDESC,
 ACTDEFN.ACTCODE,
 HISTORY.WONO, 
 HISTORY.COMPFLAG,
 HISTORY.ADDDTTM,
 HISTORY.COMMENTS,
 COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY COMPSTSB.UNITID) AS numDups
 FROM   (IMSV7.COMPSTSB COMPSTSB INNER JOIN IMSV7.HISTORY HISTORY ON
 COMPSTSB.COMPKEY=HISTORY.COMPKEY) INNER JOIN IMSV7.ACTDEFN ACTDEFN ON 
 HISTORY.ACTKEY=ACTDEFN.ACTKEY
 WHERE  HISTORY.COMPFLAG='Y' AND  NOT (ACTDEFN.ACTCODE='DBR' OR     ACTDEFN.ACTCODE='IN')
 )a
 WHERE a.numDups >1 
 ORDER BY COMPSTSB.UNITTYPE, COMPSTSB.UNITID, HISTORY.ADDDTTM
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are concerned about having duplicate values of `UNITID` in the `IMSV7.COMPSTSB` table.  If so adding this join to your query should enable ou to identify them:

```
 JOIN (SELECT COMPSTSB.UNITID
         FROM IMSV7.COMPSTSB
        GROUP BY COMPSTSB.UNITID
       HAVING COUNT(COMPSTSB.UNITID) > 1) dups
   ON DUPS.UNITID = COMPSTSB.UNITID
 JOIN IMSV7.HISTORY HISTORY
```

Here's the full query:

```
 SELECT COMPSTSB.UNITID
      , COMPSTSB.UNITTYPE
      , ACTDEFN.ACTDESC
      , ACTDEFN.ACTCODE
      , HISTORY.WONO
      , HISTORY.COMPFLAG
      , HISTORY.ADDDTTM
      , HISTORY.COMMENTS
   FROM IMSV7.COMPSTSB COMPSTSB
   JOIN (SELECT COMPSTSB.UNITID
           FROM IMSV7.COMPSTSB
          GROUP BY COMPSTSB.UNITID
         HAVING COUNT(COMPSTSB.UNITID) > 1) dups
     ON DUPS.UNITID = COMPSTSB.UNITID
   JOIN IMSV7.HISTORY HISTORY
     ON COMPSTSB.COMPKEY = HISTORY.COMPKEY
   JOIN IMSV7.ACTDEFN ACTDEFN
     ON HISTORY.ACTKEY = ACTDEFN.ACTKEY
  WHERE HISTORY.COMPFLAG = 'Y'
    AND ACTDEFN.ACTCODE NOT IN ('DBR','IN')
  ORDER BY COMPSTSB.UNITTYPE
      , COMPSTSB.UNITID
      , HISTORY.ADDDTTM;
```

Since the above query didn't work you can try outer joins to similar sub queries on each of your tables and limit to only records where the outer joined table returns data.  This will show you which tables in your query are cuasing your extra rows.:

```
 SELECT COMPSTSB.UNITID
      , COMPSTSB.UNITTYPE
      , ACTDEFN.ACTDESC
      , ACTDEFN.ACTCODE
      , HISTORY.WONO
      , HISTORY.COMPFLAG
      , HISTORY.ADDDTTM
      , HISTORY.COMMENTS
      , DUPS.UNITID UNITID_DUP
      , DUPS2.COMPKEY COMPKEY_DUP
      , DUPS3.ACTKEY ACTKEY_DUP
   FROM IMSV7.COMPSTSB COMPSTSB
   JOIN IMSV7.HISTORY HISTORY
     ON COMPSTSB.COMPKEY = HISTORY.COMPKEY
   JOIN IMSV7.ACTDEFN ACTDEFN
     ON HISTORY.ACTKEY = ACTDEFN.ACTKEY
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT COMPSTSB.UNITID
           FROM IMSV7.COMPSTSB
          GROUP BY COMPSTSB.UNITID
         HAVING COUNT(COMPSTSB.UNITID) > 1) dups
     ON DUPS.UNITID = COMPSTSB.UNITID
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT HISTORY.COMPKEY
           FROM IMSV7.HISTORY
          GROUP BY HISTORY.COMPKEY
         HAVING COUNT(HISTORY.COMPKEY) > 1) dups2
     ON DUPS.UNITID = COMPSTSB.UNITID
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT ACTDEFN.ACTKEY
           FROM IMSV7.ACTDEFN
          GROUP BY ACTDEFN.ACTKEY
         HAVING COUNT(ACTDEFN.ACTKEY) > 1) dups3
     ON DUPS.UNITID = COMPSTSB.UNITID
  WHERE HISTORY.COMPFLAG = 'Y'
    AND ACTDEFN.ACTCODE NOT IN ('DBR','IN')
    AND ( DUPS.UNITID   IS NOT NULL OR
          DUPS2.COMPKEY IS NOT NULL OR
          DUPS3.ACTKEY  IS NOT NULL)
  ORDER BY COMPSTSB.UNITTYPE
      , COMPSTSB.UNITID
      , HISTORY.ADDDTTM;
```

Comment: I probally wrote my original question poorly.  Your query returns zero rows with both > and with <.  If I use = on the HAVING COUNT(COMPSTSB.UNITID) > 1) dups line then I get the same results as my original query, which shows both rows that have unique UNITID  and rows that have duplicate UNITID (which is all I want to return, all the duplicates)

Comment: That just means that all instances of UNITID in table COMPSTSB are unique.  The question is which of the tables you're joining to has more rows than you desire.  Either your HISTORY Table has multiple instances of COMPKEY, or your ACTDEFN table has multiple instances of ACTKEY.  You can try similar joins on those tables to find the culprit.